# Dynamically aenerated herf will not download file after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, base64

I am pulling a list of documents names and ID's from a database, and putting them in a unordered list, For example:

```
<ul id="list">
   <li onmouseover="onHover(docNumber)"> 
      <a herf="#" id="docNumber">DocName</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When I hover over the list item it will run the function to populate herf and download attributes by calling the database and getting the data based on the DocNumber.

```
function onHover(DMRSN){
     const types = [
       'application/msword',
       'application/vnd.ms-excel',
       'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
       'application/pdf',
       'image/png',
       'image/jpeg',
       'video/mp4'
   ]

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'blob.php?get=data',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {DMRSN: DMRSN},
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);

            const docNumber = data[0].DMRSN;
            const name = data[0].FileName;
            const ext = name.split('.')[1];
            const Filename = data[0].FileName;
            const Document = data[0].Document;
            let type; 

            switch(ext){
                case 'doc':
                    type = types[0];
                    break;
                case 'dotx':
                    type = types[0];
                    break;
                case 'docx':
                    type = types[0];
                    break;
                case 'xls':
                    type = types[1];
                    break;
                case 'xlsx':
                    type = types[1];
                    break;
                case 'xlsm':    
                    type = types[1];
                    break;
                case 'pptx':    
                    type = types[2];
                    break;    
                case 'ppt':    
                    type = types[2];
                    break;     
                case 'pdf':    
                    type = types[3];
                    break;
                case 'png':    
                    type = types[4];
                    break; 
                case 'jpeg':    
                    type = types[5];
                    break;     
                case 'mp4':    
                    type = types[6];
                    break;     
            }


            $('#' + docNumber).attr('herf', 'data:' + type + ';base64, ' + Document);
            $('#' + docNumber).attr('download', Filename);

            //console.log(ext);
            //window.open('data:'+ type +';base64,' + data[0].Document, data[0].FileName)


        },
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

}
```

when I click the element, nothing will download. I checked to see of the a element was being clicked with this snip of code and it is, just the file is not downloading.

```
$('#list').on('click','li a',  function(){

        console.log('click');
    });
```

when I look in DevTools I can see that everything is set, but nothing will download when I click.
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried target="_blank"?

Comment: `herf` should be `href`. It's an innocuous typo in the title and text, but a total failure in the code.

Comment: In your code, you’ve written ‘herf’ instead of ‘href’ on the link element.

Comment: @Barmar  Wow! Thank you! Can't believe something so small had me pulling my hair out for days. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have misspelled `href` attribute, replaced `herf` with `href` and works perfectly.